# How to view the sharepoint library type

Tags: library

I created several libraries in sharepoint, I want to know the library type but didn't find the way. Anyone know that?

Answer (score 1):

you can try "Site Actions --> View All Contents", in the all contents page, you can see that SharePoint has shown you all your libraries categorized by there types.

Comment: Thanks Jony, Does this worked for both sharepoint 2007 and sharepoint 2010?

Comment: It works for SP2010, while for SP2007, I just can't remember :(